# Forward all VNC ports using SSH

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

Is there any way to forward all VNC ports (59XX) from remote machine to local machine 59XX ports?

Currently I have aliases that do the following:

```
ssh -p <remote_port> remote_ip -L5901:localhost:5901 -L5902:localhost:5902 -L590...
```

I have to frequently login to a lot of VNC sessions.

I was wondering if there is any way (like wildcard) to forward all  59XX ports to my local 59XX ports?
e.g. `ssh -p <remote_port> remote_ip -L59**:localhost:59**`

without putting nearly hundreds of -L switch to my ssh command?

Comment: Start a local socks proxy with ``-D 1080`` and configure your vnc client to use this proxy. This options is called dynamic application-level port forwarding.